# ObservableCollection binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a ObservableCollection which holds records of custom type Item. I use that collection as a binding for a ListView in WPF. That class Item also implements the interface INotifyPropertyChanged. 
When I update some of the records in the ListView, I can see the change in the ListView.

All this data comes from a WCF service. When I call the client object for the service and call a delete method to delete an item that belongs to the ObservableCollection, the record gets deleted in the DB but the items in the ListView are not updated.
Is this how it is supposed to work, or should I remove the item from the collection manually when I delete it from the DB with the service call?

Thanks

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" Height="244" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,25,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="485" >
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu AllowDrop="False">
                    <MenuItem Name="openRecord" Header="Open" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
                    <MenuItem Name="deleteRecord" Header="Delete" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="list_UserItems_ItemMouseDoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title" Width="200" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedByName}" Header="Created By" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedOn}" Header="Created On" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ExpirationDate}" Header="Expires" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post the Xaml - specifically the binding code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your situation you have two things in place

1 - An `ObservableCollection` for showing data in `ListView` which you are getting through `WCF` Service.

2 - You are performing delete operation through WCF on DB

Most probably you will be calling `WCF` service method to delete record from DB and passing it  object which have to be deleted in parameters. If this or similar is the case then you are not making any change in `ObservableCollection` which is bound to `ListView`. This means your View won't be affected in any way

You should delete the record from `ObservableCollection` manually to update the list or after deletion you should ask for new list from `DB` through `WCF` and replace the old `ObservableCollection` with new list retrieved through `WCF`

Comment: I thought since the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, when a change happens to a object of the class, it will throw a notification and the collection ill catch it and update itself.

Comment: Change in object is not enough. Object needs to be removed from collection if it is deleted

Comment: We use the same type of implementations here.  Once you delete with the service - remove it from the collection (remove immediately or remove when service confirms deletion).  You should not ask for a new list here.  This can hurt the performance of your application.